# Legality of the Cat Lawyer video

Tags: contempt-of-court

You may have seen the [recent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9f9eDBpnkaU) of the lawyer who couldn't turn off the cat filter during a Zoom trial.

What struck me about it is the legal warning in the top left frame warning that it is prohibited to record or livestream the hearing. And yet somebody recorded it.

Is somebody going to face contempt charges for this?

Comment: Wasnt it the judge who released it?

Comment: I don't know who it was. But could the judge legally record it?

Comment: I dont know, but Im not sure who is going to hold the judge in contempt if it was him.

Comment: If there was nothing about the actual case visible, and the cat lawyer sees the funny side of it I would think it’s legal. If that lawyer doesn’t like it, not sure. But taking the judge to court would likely be a bad idea, both legally and socially.

Comment: They were in contempt of cat.

Comment: @Studoku, that is an appalling pun. I wish I'd thought of it.

Answer (score 5):

The warning notice is intended for viewers and participants, not for the court to make its own official record of the proceedings.

Presumably, it was this court record that the judge released for *educational purposes* under his own Order via [Twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/JudgeFergusonTX/status/1359202090824966151).  In which case, there has been no contempt of court.

Comment: I rather doubt the Judge bothered with a legal formality for that short snippet...

Comment: An order of the judge does not necessarily need to be that formal. It depends on the circumstances and as it's his court he can just [make it so](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=FaLyasJPyUU)

Answer (score -1):

Last night's news included a 2 minute segment, ['I'm not a cat'](https://www.ctvnews.ca/video?clipId=2137407).

District Court Judge, the Honorable Roy Ferguson, clearly indicates why he released the video to the public:

> This is a time when people are down, and depressed and lonely.
> And angry at each other, and at the government.
> …
> Everyone is enjoying it.
> The feedback is all positive.
> People are happy to see it, and they're laughing.
> And I hear that that's something we need more of.

Unless he released it without the permission of the embarrassed lawyer, which is highly unlikely, he did nothing inappropriate.

Comment: Why would the court need the lawyer's permission?